# Cannot get Facebook ads_management extended permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get statistics on my facebook ad campaigns. I've followed Facebook own guide, and I've created an app and so on. However I'm unable to get ads_management permission. If I use the Graph Explorer and its "Get Access Token", I cannot select ads_management under extended permissions, the option is simply not there.

I've also tried just sending a request to the Facebook api as follows:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY-REDIRECT_URI&scope=ads_management&response_type=token";

Which does get me a access token, but not one with ads_management permission

Any thoughts?

Edit: My app is not whitelisted, but unless I've misunderstood the guide, it does not have to be, as long as I'm a developer on the app, is this correct?

Comment: Could be a Facebook bug. It's also no longer working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of the Facebook Ads API guide is that the ads_management extended permission is only granted to whitelisted apps. So if the Graph endpoint you're hitting requires that permission then you'll have to get your app approved. Check out the getting started overview https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview