# In C# Facebook MVC app template, how to get ads_read permission for my app?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebooksdk.net

I'm using Facebook Template, as shown [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app). I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook by Microsoft and Facebook by Outercurve Foundation nuget packages.

Original code in HomeController looks like this:

```
    [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
```

When I tried to add ads-related permissions like that:

```
    [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos", "ads_management", "ads_read")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
```

nohting changed. I expected that my app will generate two permission screens when I access it, just the way Graph Api Explorer does. Ads-related permissions should be on second screen. But it didn't, it simply displayed only the first screen, requesting access to my public profile.

So where / how I should declare my app needs access to ads and insights?

I already can read them, if I manually provide access token with proper permissions (for example, from PHP code). Only thing I don't know how to do is obtaining proper token - or forcing package to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865274/cannot-get-facebook-ads-management-extended-permission?rq=1) question, your app needs to get approved first. Look at [this overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview).

Comment: The same app id, used with php & js app, can get this permission without any problem, so no, that's not the case here.