# Facebook ads authorisation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

My application use facebook authentication to ask the user permissions to manage his ads. i use the following  scope:'public_profile,ads_management,ads_management'
but in the login window it shows only public profile which will an invalid access token for the ads management.[image]

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25901780/5410373

> the ads_management extended permission is only granted to whitelisted apps. So if the Graph endpoint you're hitting requires that permission then you'll have to get your app approved. Check out the getting started overview https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview

and this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753070/5410373

> All permissions except
>
> - public_profile
> - user_friends
> - email
>
> require a review of your app by Facebook before you can use them publically. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review